# At which point does a control's event delegate call the base code

Tags: c#, events, delegates

For example, the constructor of a custom derived listbox has:

```
this.KeyDown += listbox_KeyDown;
```

And this is implemented as:

```
private void listbox_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
}
```

At which point is the base parent code called?

Without delegates, it would like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown( KeyEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnKeyDown( e );
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: It was already called, you would not get the event otherwise.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the base is called before any code is executed.